# Interactive Book/Magazine publishing framework for Android

Tags: android

There are tools that convert pdf to html5.
If you've heard of Baker, it's a framework that allows you to import these generated html5 publications and create a newsstand app.

Baker began to support IOS only, but few years ago Android support was also available.

The problem is that BakerFramework is pretty laggy on Android with most of it's features don't work properly. ( Or.. i'm doing something wrong that makes my app unstable )

My question is:
Is there any alternative framework or way to do the same thing on Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this https://digitalpublishing.acrobat.com/welcome.html

**DPS(Digital Publishing Suite).**

Digital Publishing Suite is a complete solution to create, distribute, monetize, and optimize engaging content and publications for smartphones and tablets.

In general, the steps to build a native DPS android app to show digital content are the following.

1. Need DPS Application account and DPS App Builder credentials.
2. Content creation : Creates articles with InDesign.
3. Android/iOs apps using DPS App Builder.